# How do I get my program to restart properly? (Brick Breaker)

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, java-2d, thread-sleep

When gameover is true and I call the startGame method from the DOWN button KeyListener, it breaks my game and doesn't allow me to click the exit button on the JFrame and the paddle doesn't work anymore. Please help.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Image;
public class AustinsBrickBreaker {
    JFrame window;
    DrawPanel panel;
    public AustinsBrickBreaker() {
        window = new JFrame("Brick Breaker");
        panel = new DrawPanel();
        window.setSize(800, 592);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(panel);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);
    }
    public void go() {
        panel.startGame();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AustinsBrickBreaker game = new AustinsBrickBreaker();
        game.go();
    }
}
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DrawPanel extends JPanel implements KeyListener {
    final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 592;
    BufferedImage buffer;
    public static Brick[][] bricks = new Brick[3][5];
    Paddle paddle;
    Ball ball;
    int score = 0;
    int lives = 3;
    boolean gameover = false;
    Image brickImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("brick.png");
    Image brickImage2 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("brick2.png");
    Image brickImage3 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("brick3.png");
    Image brickImage4 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("brick4.png");
    Image brickImage5 = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("brick5.png");
    Image paddleImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("paddle.png");
    Image background = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("background.jpg");
    Image ballImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("ball.png");
    Image heartImage = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("heart.png");
    public DrawPanel() {
        setIgnoreRepaint(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) paddle.left = true;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) paddle.right = true;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_UP && gameover) {
            gameover = false;
            score = 0;
            lives = 3;
            startGame();
        }
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN && gameover) System.exit(0);
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        int key = e.getKeyCode();
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) paddle.left = false;
        if (key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) paddle.right = false;
    }
    public int count() {
        int count = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < DrawPanel.bricks.length; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < DrawPanel.bricks[r].length; c++)
        if (!bricks[r][c].visible) count++;
        else
        break;
        int returner = 0;
        if (count == 15) returner = 1;
        return returner;
    }
    public void initialize() {
        buffer = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        for (int r = 0; r < DrawPanel.bricks.length; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < DrawPanel.bricks[r].length; c++)
        DrawPanel.bricks[r][c] = new Brick(c * 150 + 50, r * 60 + 30, 100, 50);
        ball = new Ball(390, 200, 20, 20, 10);
        paddle = new Paddle(350, 510, 100, 20, 8);
    }
    public void updateMovement() {
        paddle.move();
        ball.move();
    }
    public void checkCollisions() {
        if (paddle.x <= 20) paddle.x = 20;
        if (paddle.x >= 679) paddle.x = 679;
        if (ball.x < 21) {
            ball.left = false;
            ball.right = true;
        }
        if (ball.x > 761) {
            ball.left = true;
            ball.right = false;
        }
        if (ball.y < 21) {
            ball.up = false;
            ball.down = true;
        }
        if (paddle.getBounds().intersects(ball.getBounds())) ball.swap();
        for (int r = 0; r < DrawPanel.bricks.length; r++)
        for (int c = 0; c < DrawPanel.bricks[r].length; c++) {
            if (ball.getBounds().intersects(DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].getBounds()) && !DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].collision) {
                ball.swap();
                bricks[r][c].collide();
                score += 10;
            }
        }
    }
    public void drawBuffer() {
        Graphics2D b = buffer.createGraphics();
        b.drawImage(background, 0, 0, null);
        if (!gameover) {
            for (int l = 0; l < lives; l++)
            b.drawImage(heartImage, 20 * l + 620, 535, null);
            b.drawString("Score: " + score, 700, 550);
            b.drawImage(paddleImage, paddle.getX(), paddle.getY(), null);
            b.drawImage(ballImage, ball.getX(), ball.getY(), null);
            for (int r = 0; r < DrawPanel.bricks.length; r++)
            for (int c = 0; c < DrawPanel.bricks[r].length; c++) {
                if (bricks[r][c].visible == true)
                if (bricks[r][c].colour == 1)
                b.drawImage(brickImage, DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].getX(), DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].getY(), null);
                else if (bricks[r][c].colour == 2)
                b.drawImage(brickImage2, DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].getX(), DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].getY(), null);
                else if (bricks[r][c].colour == 3)
                b.drawImage(brickImage3, DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].getX(), DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].getY(), null);
                else if (bricks[r][c].colour == 4)
                b.drawImage(brickImage4, DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].getX(), DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].getY(), null);
                else if (bricks[r][c].colour == 5)
                b.drawImage(brickImage5, DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].getX(), DrawPanel.bricks[r][c].getY(), null);
            }
            b.dispose();
            } else {
            b.drawString("G A M E O V E R !", 340, 300);
            b.drawString("G A M E O V E R !", 341, 300);
            b.drawString("G A M E O V E R !", 342, 300);
            b.drawString("Press ↑ To Play Again!", 332, 320);
            b.drawString("Press ↓ To Exit :(", 342, 340);
        }
    }
    public void drawScreen() {
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) this.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(buffer, 0, 0, this);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();
    }
    public void startGame() {
        initialize();
        while (!gameover) {
            try {
                updateMovement();
                checkCollisions();
                drawBuffer();
                drawScreen();
                Thread.sleep(15);
                if (ball.y > 562 && lives != -1) {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    lives -= 1;
                    ball.x = 390;
                    ball.y = 200;
                    ball.left = false;
                    ball.right = false;
                    paddle.x = 350;
                }
                if (lives == -1) {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    gameover = true;
                    drawBuffer();
                    drawScreen();
                }
                //Replace Bricks
                if (count() == 1) {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    startGame();
                }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
/*--|--|--|--| GAME CLASSES |--|--|--|--*/
class Brick {
    int x, y, width, height, colour;
    boolean collision, visible;
    public Brick(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.collision = false;
        this.visible = true;
        this.colour = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    public void collide() {
        if (collision == false) {
            visible = false;
            collision = true;
        }
    }
}
class Paddle {
    int x, y, width, height, speed;
    boolean left, right;
    public Paddle(int x, int y, int w, int h, int s) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.speed = s;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    public void move() {
        if (left) x -= speed;
        if (right) x += speed;
    }
}
class Ball {
    int x, y, width, height, speed;
    boolean up, down, left, right;
    public Ball(int x, int y, int w, int h, int s) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.speed = s;
        this.up = false;
        this.down = true;
    }
    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }
    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }
    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(getX(), getY(), getWidth(), getHeight());
    }
    public void move() {
        if (up) y -= speed;
        if (down) y += speed;
        if (left) x -= (float) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
        if (right) x += (float) Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5);
    }
    public void swap() {
        if (up) {
            down = true;
            up = false;
            } else if (down) {
            up = true;
            down = false;
        }
        double r = Math.random();
        if (r <= 0.5) {
            left = false;
            right = true;
            } else if (r > 0.5) {
            left = true;
            right = false;
        } else left = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: illegal Skype request removed. Code link (which is also not allowed) removed and actual code pasted. Now please consider condensing your code and your problem into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem, in other words, a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Your code completely ignores Swing threading rules, and this is somehow allowed when first run, since when first run, the `startGame()` method is called in the main thread off of the Swing event thread. But when it is called a second time, it is then called on the event thread, and this time, all those sleep calls put the Swing event thread **and your application** to sleep. The solution: learn about Swing threading rules, and have your application obey these rules, including not calling Thread.sleep, or having forever loops called on the event thread.

see: [Lesson: Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).

Answer (score 2):

## This is not an answer, but a very long comment

First, `getGraphics` is NOT how custom painting works in Swing and you should never use it.

Start by taking a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing.

Swing uses a passive rendering approaching, meaning that it's painting process can take place at any time, for any reason most without your interaction or knowledge, under your current approach, you could end up with intermediate flickering which be near impossible to diagnose or repeat.

If you want control over the painting (active painting), have a look at [`BufferStrategy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferStrategy.html) and [BufferStrategy and BufferCapabilities](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/bufferstrategy.html)

Second, don't use `KeyListener`, there are a very limited number of circumstances I might consider using `KeyListener`, but this is not one of them and when you find yourself wanting to respond to key events, you should start with [the key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Third, don't use `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage`, but instead use `ImageIO`, it supports more images, it loads the image first before returning (rather than using a background thread) and throws an `IOException` when the image can't be loaded.  See [Reading/Loading an Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) for more details

Fourth, you are violating the single thread rules of Swing.  Basically, because the way the system works, `main` is called within what is called the "main" thread, but Swing runs in it's own thread (AKA The Event Dispatching Thread).

So when you first start, `go` is running in the "main" thread, but when you call `start` from your `KeyListener`, you're running within the EDT, meaning that you "game-loop" will block the EDT and nothing will ever paint again and the user won't be able to interact with your program.

See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details and [How to Use Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for a possible solution

Comment: Yup, yup, all great advice